# Clojure List -> Vector

Tags: vector, clojure

I need to create a function. Within this I need the following to happen:

```
List 1: '(a 5 6)
List 2: '(c 8 10)
List 3: '(d 4 9)
```

Above are the lists. I need to ignore the 1st column of each list (this being a, c and d.) and then put the 2nd column in a vector. Then do the same for the 3rd column but a separate vector. Once this is done I'll carry out some small arithmetic between the two and write the results of each into a third vector.

I have very little Clojure experience and come from a Java background. I've tried to use `let`

By doing so I've only been able to create a var which stores the 2nd and 3rd item in a single list only. (e.g. List 1's 5 & 6.) However I need the vector to be `[5 8 4]`.

Comment: This sounds like matrix arithmetic.  Depending on what else you want to do with the data, [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/wiki) might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn answer [& [list-1 list-2 list-3 :as lists]]
   (->> lists                    ; ((a 5 6) (c 8 10) (d 4 9))
        (map rest)               ; ((5 6) (8 10) (4 9))
        (apply map vector)       ; ([5 8 4] [6 10 9])
        (apply small-arithmetic) ; (small-arithmetic [5 8 4] [6 10 9])
  ))
```

*assuming `small-arithmetic` is  a function taking the desired two vectors and returning the third vector.*

Comment: Can you just run me through your answer please? So lists 1, 2 and 3 are all within a list. So a list of lists. Would they be put in the function as a parameter like that? If it's a list of lists would this change your answer at all..

Comment: I have declared a variadic function to collect the three argument lists in `lists`. `(answer list-1 list-2 list-3)` is the intended invocation. An equivalent declaration would be `(defn answer [list-1 list-2 list-3] (->> [list-1 list-2 list-3] ...;(as above)`

Comment: If the input is a list of lists you chould just `(defn answer [lists] ...)` and invoke it e. g. `(answer [list-1 list-2 list-3])`

Comment: I'll give it a run through, I'm fairly confident I'm going to struggle with its implementation though so I'll keep it open for a while!

Comment: How would I do the function for the small-arithmetic?

Comment: `(defn small-arithmetic [v1 v2] ...)` , or if you want a list of vectors `(defn small-arithmetic [vectors] ...)` But then you need to leave out `apply` in the last line of `answer`.

Comment: I meant the arithmetic in the actual function :3

Comment: "I'll carry out some small arithmetic between the two and write the results of each into a third vector" -- I can't help you with that unless you are more specific.

Comment: multiplying each item of the two vectors with the others. e.g. item 1 in vector 1 multiplied by item 1 and vector 2.